# Navigation in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

I have a task to navigate on google map. I  have to find out the names and set as source and destination in google map. Is there any possiblity to do this. I have no idea. please help  me.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this.

```
double lat,lng;
//set the values for lat and lng
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr="+Double.toString(lat)+","+Double.toString(lng)));
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

From the `Uri` you provide to the `Intent` you can set destination and source locations.

However you need to share your work so that people can understand what is the problem you have.